# How did "inner join" and "outer join" get their names?

Tags: sql

Curious question but why do we call it `inner` vs. `outer join`?  The terms `join`, `left`, and `right` make sense to me but `inner` and `outer` isn't so obvious.

Comment: try programmers.stackexchange.com for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is relational algebra behind each query. Venn diagrams provide a quick visual understanding of this. Check this [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)

- This is a [intersection](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Venn0001.svg)
- This is a [union](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Venn0111.svg)
- And a [Difference](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Venn0110.svg)

...oopss...closed

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood SQL is an relational algebra engine, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra

Comment: Why are they called that in the relational algebra?